# Compile Error variable not initialized

Tags: java

I've written program here to prompt a user for 3 integer variables compare them and find out which one is the largest middle and smallest, that part works fine. My issue is if you look at my first if statement I am trying to save those values each into a variable in memory, I keep getting variables not initialized errors. Any help would be great! I am basically wanting to store those values to continue writing more code to compare them and find out if they create a triangle or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class TriangleProgram
    {
       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

          int x;
          System.out.print("Enter X: ");
          x = input.nextInt();

          int y;
          System.out.print("Enter Y: ");
          y = input.nextInt();

          int z;
          System.out.print("Enter Z: ");
          z = input.nextInt();

          System.out.println();

          int largest;
          int middle;
          int smallest;


          if(x > y && x > z && y > z)
          {
             System.out.println("Largeset Number: " + x);
             System.out.println("Middle Number: " + y);
             System.out.println("Smallest Number: " + z);

             x = largest;
             y = middle;
             z = smallest;

          }

          else if(x > y && x > z && z > y)
          {
            System.out.println("Largeset Number: " + x);
            System.out.println("Middle Number: " + z);
            System.out.println("Smallest Number: " + y);
          }

          else if(y > x && y > z && x > z)
          {
            System.out.println("Largeset Number: " + y);
            System.out.println("Middle Number: " + x);
            System.out.println("Smallest Number: " + z);
          }

          else if(y > x && y > z && z > x)
          {
            System.out.println("Largeset Number: " + y);
            System.out.println("Middle Number: " + z);
            System.out.println("Smallest Number: " + x); 
          }

          else if(z > x && z > y && x > y)
          {
            System.out.println("Largeset Number: " + z);
            System.out.println("Middle Number: " + x);
            System.out.println("Smallest Number: " + y);
          }

          else
          {
            System.out.println("Largeset Number: " + z);
            System.out.println("Middle Number: " + y);
            System.out.println("Smallest Number: " + x);
          }


       }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you want `x = largest;
             y = middle;
             z = smallest;`. It seems more like you want `largest = x;
             middle = y;
             smalles = z;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip the assignments. They're backwards.

```
largest  = x;
middle   = y;
smallest = z;
```

Answer (score 2):

In

```
         x = largest;
         y = middle;
         z = smallest;
```

You're assigning the value of largest (which you haven't assigned anything to) to x (and likewise for middle to y and smallest to z).  That's why you're getting a variable not initialized errors, and it's probably not what you want to do.  Try:

```
         largest = x;
         middle = y;
         smallest = z;
```

Answer (score 1):

The if part you want to do

```
Largest = x;
Middle = y ;
smallest = z;
```